# Is there a built-in method to binary search through the entries in the .NET EventLog.Entries collection?

Tags: c#, .net, event-log, binary-search

I am developing a log parsing service that captures specific security events in the Windows Event Log.  My initial thought was to use Microsoft's [LogParser](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en), but I am not looking for any functionality beyond selecting specific Instance/Event IDs already known in advance.

After some benchmarking, I found that iterating over the entire .NET `EventLog.Entries` collection was over 3 times faster at pulling data than querying Microsoft's LogParser.

Ultimately, the data to be pulled will be saved in a SQL Server database. Since the service will perform this duty daily, I wish to avoid duplicate entries, and I will need a way to find the next entry in the `EventLog.Entries` collection that is not already in the database. I can begin inserting to the database once I've found that initial entry.

I was just about to write a binary search to find this entry using the most recent `DATETIME` timestamp field from the database and comparing it to the `TimeWritten` property from an item in the `EventLog.Entries` collection. This I can do, but I am wondering if there is already a built-in method to perform this search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing my own since I could not find a built-in implementation:

```
/// <summary>
/// Performs a binary search on a specified EventLogEntryCollection's
/// TimeWritten property
/// </summary>
/// <param name="entries">The collection to search</param>
/// <param name="value">The timestamp value being searched</param>
/// <param name="low">The lower-bound search index</param>
/// <param name="high">The upper-bound search index</param>
/// <returns>The index of a matching timestamp, or -1 if not found</returns>
private int BinarySearch(EventLogEntryCollection entries, DateTime value, int low, int high)
{
    if (high < low)
        return -1;
    int mid = low + ((high - low) / 2);
    if (entries[mid].TimeWritten > value)
        return BinarySearch(entries, value, low, mid - 1);
    else if (entries[mid].TimeWritten < value)
        return BinarySearch(entries, value, mid + 1, high);
    else
        return mid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `EventLogEntryCollection`, but if you need a generic binary search algorithm, you can use the one implemented in [PowerCollections](http://books.google.si/books?id=AxW2pg1LYGcC&pg=PA296&lpg=PA296&dq=powercollections+binarysearch&source=bl&ots=54KoH9nUpx&sig=3XpEpwGPCvU7SHllal6OUwXg-SM&hl=en&ei=1iXkSfbmMo6PsAaf7MinCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1#PPA297,M1) library.